# How can I connect to an Access database from Java using JDBC?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

How can I connect to an Access database from Java using JDBC?

**Code provided in OP's comment**

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException { 
    // connection object
    Connection con = null;

    // database url
    String connectionString = "jdbc:odbc:Driver= " 
            + "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + dbPath;

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("connot load driver class");
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try asking google for `jdbc msaccess`?

Comment: yes :)
but i still have a problem

Comment: So maybe you can tell us about your problem, what did you try so far?

Comment: public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        // connection object
        Connection con = null;
        // database url
        String connectionString = "jdbc:odbc:Driver= "
                + "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + dbPath;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("connot load driver class");
        }
        return con;
    }

Comment: @soad el-hayek, instead of posting your code on a post section, update your question rather with your code and the stacktrace that you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

// set this to a MS Access DB you have on your machine

String filename = "d:/java/mdbTEST.mdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
database+= filename.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}"; // add on to the end 
// now we can get the connection from the DriverManager
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");
```

refer http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2

Comment: I'VE use the same
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        String connectionString = "jdbc:odbc:Driver= "
                + "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + dbPath;
        try {
            // load the driver class
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("connot load driver class");
        }
        // return the connection object
        return con;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the ODBC-JDBC bridge for that.

See
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2
for sample source code.
and 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXkGMu70HuM so see how to setup the data source (DSN).

Comment: for the video  , i've win 7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

An alternative - [JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-mt/) - which has a client/server architecture is also available...

This means the Java application and Access database can reside on different machines.

The following link will give you an idea of what goes where --

[OpenLink Milti-tier JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://goo.gl/GVuYj)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NewClass {
static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename";
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
public void dataQuery(String queryData) {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryData);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(1));
    }
}    
catch (Exception e) {            
    System.out.println("error Accessing");
}finally {
    try {
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("error closing ");}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ODBC connection to connect to Access Database from Java.

See the following example

http://www.csnotes32.com/2014/11/how-to-read-write-update-and-list-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Now that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java (since Java SE 8), future readers should consider using the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver instead. For more information see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)